# Can't click on items in ListView with custom adapter

Tags: android, listview

I am trying to write an application which takes items from a database and populates rows within a ListView. I can't click on the items after tapping on the rows and the dpad won't go to any of the rows either. I am using a custom Adapter.

**Tweet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
        android:padding="6dip" 
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textUser"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textStyle="bold" 
                android:text="NAME"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textDate"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#333333"
                android:text="DATE" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textTweet"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TWEET" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

**Activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

</ListView>
```

**Oncreate Method**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            ListView view = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);     
        MyArrayAdapter theAdapter = new MyArrayAdapter(tweetDb,this);

        //setContentView(theAdapter.getView(0, null, null));
        view.setAdapter(theAdapter);
        view.setOnItemClickListener( new OnItemClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position,
                    long id) 
            {
                //Tweet theTweet = (Tweet)parent.getAdapter().getItem(position);
                //saved.insert(theTweet);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.v("SCHEMA", "onItemClick fired!");
            }
        } );
    }
```

**Adapter Class getView**

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(
    Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE
    );

    View tweetView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tweet, null);

    TextView textTweet = (TextView)  tweetView.findViewById(R.id.textTweet);    
    textTweet.setText(items.get(position).getTweet());

    textTweet = (TextView)tweetView.findViewById(R.id.textUser);
    textTweet.setText(items.get(position).getName());

    textTweet = (TextView)tweetView.findViewById(R.id.textDate);
    textTweet.setText(textFormat.format(items.get(position).getCreated()));

    return tweetView;
}
```

**MyArrayAdapter Class**

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.DataSetObserver;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyArrayAdapter implements ListAdapter
{

    private ArrayList<Tweet> items;
    private Context context;
    private SimpleDateFormat textFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");

    public MyArrayAdapter(TweetDbSource db, Context context)
    {
        items = new ArrayList<Tweet>();
        this.context = context;
        Cursor cursor = db.getReadableDatabase().query("Tweet", null, null, null, null, null, null);

        while (!cursor.isLast())
        {
                cursor.moveToNext();
                items.add(new Tweet(cursor.getLong(0),cursor.getLong(1),cursor.getString(2),cursor.getString(3),
                                cursor.getString(4),new Date(),cursor.getInt(6)));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) 
    {
        return items.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) 
    {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int arg0) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(
        Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE
        );

        OnClickListener saveTweet = new OnClickListener() 
        {
              public void onClick(View v) 
              {
                  Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              }
        };
        View tweetView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tweet, null);

        TextView textTweet = (TextView)  tweetView.findViewById(R.id.textTweet);    
        textTweet.setText(items.get(position).getTweet());

        textTweet = (TextView)tweetView.findViewById(R.id.textUser);
        textTweet.setText(items.get(position).getName());

        textTweet = (TextView)tweetView.findViewById(R.id.textDate);
        textTweet.setText(textFormat.format(items.get(position).getCreated()));

        return tweetView;
    }


    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return items.size() == 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void registerDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver arg0) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void unregisterDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver arg0) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled(int arg0) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

}
```

Toast or log is not working, that's how I can tell it's not working

**Updated getView Method**

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {
             OnClickListener SaveView = new OnClickListener() {
             @SuppressLint("NewApi")
            public void onClick(View v) 
             {
               Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               v.callOnClick();
             }
         };
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(
            Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE
            );
            View tweetView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tweet, null);

            TextView textTweet = (TextView)  tweetView.findViewById(R.id.textTweet);    
            textTweet.setText(items.get(position).getTweet());

            textTweet = (TextView)tweetView.findViewById(R.id.textUser);
            textTweet.setText(items.get(position).getName());

            textTweet = (TextView)tweetView.findViewById(R.id.textDate);
            textTweet.setText(textFormat.format(items.get(position).getCreated()));
            tweetView.setOnClickListener(SaveView);
            return tweetView;
    }
```

**UPDATE**

The issue was solved and I figured it out :D I had to return true instead of false in these two methods within my adapter class!

```
@Override
    public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() 
    {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled(int arg0) 
    {
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Not related to this question, but recommended to re-use convertView, if(convertView == null) then only you should inflate it. otherwise re-use convertView

Comment: you should include your `MyArrayAdapter` code as it can also be the source of your problem.

Comment: I included the MyArrayAdapter Class code

Answer (score 68):

Usually this happens because the items in your listview are in focus. Try adding

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

in your custom listview row

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:padding="6dip" 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">
```

Comment: it's all good, I just had to add set areAllItemsEnabled in the adapter to true and isEnabled to true

Comment: I have also tried this solution in the past and it didn't work with the adapter trick, but now I got it to work. Thanks pal, I appreciate trying to help!

Comment: For me this `descendantFocusability` solution worked, and the `areAllItemsEnabled`/`isEnabled` did not. Can't get why.

Comment: This should be the answer.. +1 for elegant solution, and it does not block buttons!

Comment: Yes, it should be the answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

I usually put the click listener in the adapter itself:

```
@Override
      public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        OnClickListener yourClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
              public void onClick(View v) {
                //put your desired action here
                v.callOnClick();
              }
          };

    ...

    // then add the listener to your view
    tweetView.setOnClickListener(yourClickListener);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! It's greatly appreciated!
The only this is that I can't even seem to click on any of the rows, at least it doesnt even highlight or anything

Comment: Did the toast work now but the rows do not indicate a visual feedback when pressed?  Or did the toast still not work?  It would be good to see your latest adapter code.

Comment: It still didn't work after I tried all the different solutions posted here, the code I have written right now is my latest code for my adapter

Comment: I don't see where you attached the onClick event to the view or calling the click action within the listener.  
                v.callOnClick(); 
    ...
                tweetView.setOnClickListener(saveTweet);

Comment: I added the modified version now.

Answer (score 0):

add inside onItemClick method:

```
v.setSelected(true);
```

Comment: how is this supposed to work? read the question again - OP said that neither `Toast` nor `Log` is working so it appears the `onItemClick()` is not called.

Answer (score -1):

Add the line below to your ListView xml

```
android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
```

Comment: Is your android version < 3

Comment: have you tried view.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);

Comment: yup, that didn't work either. I believe someone posted about it, but to set that through XML. I tried both ways, still I got nothing.

Answer (score -2):

Tried this?

```
        @Override
    public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
        //Set a Toast or Log over here to check.
        return true;
    }
```