# Can't Click Items In listview

Tags: android, listview

Hi I've been trying to populate a `listview` with data from a database so far I've successfully created a `listview`. But now I can't click any of the items The `listview` is totally static all I can do is scroll through it

Heres the code:

```
public class List_view extends AppCompatActivity {
    ArrayList<String> throwlist = new ArrayList<String>();
    ListView Trainlist;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_view);
        Trainlist=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.station_list);
        SQLiteDatabase db = openOrCreateDatabase("Station11.db", SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY, null);

        try{
            Cursor data_fetch = db.rawQuery("Select Station_name From Station", null);

            String[] station_array = new String[data_fetch.getCount()];
            int i= 0;
            while (data_fetch.moveToNext()) {
                String name = data_fetch.getString(data_fetch.getColumnIndex("Station_name"));
                station_array[i] = name;
                Log.d("STATION_GET!","Retrieved station " + station_array[i]);
                //Toast.makeText(List_view.this, "Retrieved station " + station_array[i] , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if(throwlist.contains(name)) {

                }
                else {
                    throwlist.add(name);
                }
            }
            data_fetch.close();
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(List_view.this, "An Error occured Retrieving your data" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        try {

            ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                    this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,throwlist);
            Trainlist.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.d("Error in listview ",e.toString());
            Toast.makeText(List_view.this, "Listview Error" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        try {
            Trainlist.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    String val = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                    String select_data = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();
                    Log.d("Inside Function!!! ",null);
                    Toast.makeText(List_view.this, val + " Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(List_view.this,"Error!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

}

I've been following the instructions on [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_list_view.htm) to do this

Any Help Is appreciated!

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15352486/cant-click-on-items-in-listview-with-custom-adapter

Comment: @NileshRathod Unfortunately that didnt help still facing the same issue

Comment: @GowthamanM Idk Man It worked for me after i commented it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following by removing the Log
it is causing NullPointerException 
`java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message`

```
 lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String val = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            String select_data = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), val + " Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
```

Comment: I dont know why but something as innocuous as that log function was causing the issue!

Comment: `Toast.makeText(getActivity(), " Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`How this line will work.it will through compile time error...listview place inside activity...activity doesnot having reference of `getActivity()`

Comment: @GowthamanM i worked out the above example inside a fragment. so getActivity.

Comment: But he is not creating fragment...he is using Activities

Comment: @GowthamanM so he might have used the applicationContext instead. and thank you for pointing out my mistake. i didnt care about wether its a fragment or activity. I will edit my answer.