# Can't click the Listview items with custom adapter

Tags: android, listview

I am trying to make an application that takes the data from database and list them in Listview rows. I want to make these items clickable so I will jump another activity by clicking them. But I can't click the items of the Listview. I will be grateful for any help. Thanks in advance.

My adapter

```
    public class OzelAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private List<Urun> urunListesi;
    Urun myUrun;

    public OzelAdapter(Activity activity, List<Urun> urunList) {
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(
                Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        //gösterilecek listeyi de alalım
        urunListesi = urunList;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return urunListesi.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Urun getItem(int position) {
        //şöyle de olabilir: public Object getItem(int position)
        return urunListesi.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
        View satirView=null;

        if(satirView==null) {


            satirView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.anasayfalist, null);
        }
        TextView textView =
                (TextView) satirView.findViewById(R.id.stokName);
        TextView textViewcount =
                (TextView) satirView.findViewById(R.id.stokCount);

        Urun asset = urunListesi.get(position);

        textView.setText(asset.getName());
        textViewcount.setText("Toplam Stok: "+asset.getQuantity());


        return satirView;
    }

}
```

My current list.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/stokName"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textSize="22dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/stokCount"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/stokName"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textSize="16dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

My activity.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.user.stoktakip.StokSayfasi">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />


        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
    </ListView>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

My activity

```
    public class StokSayfasi extends AppCompatActivity  {
    private FirebaseAuth auth;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private OzelAdapter adapter;
    public ListView listemiz;
    public Urun myUrun;
    private List<String>urunler=new ArrayList<>();
    private List<Integer>adetler=new ArrayList<>();
    public List<Urun>urunList=new ArrayList<>();
    public int count;
    DatabaseReference rootRef;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_stok_sayfasi);
        listemiz=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        registerForContextMenu(listemiz);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle(getString(R.string.app_name));
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        prepareStockData();
        adapter = new OzelAdapter(this,urunList);
        listemiz.setAdapter(adapter);


        listemiz.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                myUrun=urunList.get(i);
                startActivity(new Intent(StokSayfasi.this, DetayliListe.class));
                finish();
            }
        });







    }
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);

        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View view, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, view, menuInfo);
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.choose_menu, menu);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
        switch(item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.urungir:
                new Intent(StokSayfasi.this, DetayliListe.class);
                return true;
            case R.id.uruncikar:
                // edit stuff here
                return true;

            default:
                return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle item selection
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.urun_girdisi:
                startActivity(new Intent(StokSayfasi.this,UrunGirdisi.class));
                return true;
            case R.id.urun_ciktisi:
                startActivity(new Intent(StokSayfasi.this,UrunCiktisi.class));
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

    }

    public void prepareStockData(){
        rootRef= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Ürünler");
        rootRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                urunList.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot childSnapShot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    count=0;
                    urunler.add((String)childSnapShot.child("name").getValue());
                    count=count+((Long)childSnapShot.child("quantity").getValue()).intValue();
                    int childs=(int)childSnapShot.getChildrenCount();
                    int exit=0;
                    for (DataSnapshot childishSnapShot : childSnapShot.getChildren()){
                            try {
                                count = count + ((Long) childishSnapShot.child("quantity").getValue()).intValue();

                            }
                            catch (NullPointerException e){

                            }


                    }
                    adetler.add(count);


                }

                for(int i=0 ; i<urunler.size();i++){
                    Urun u1=new Urun(urunler.get(i),adetler.get(i));
                    urunList.add(u1);
                }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }


            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }


}
```

EDIT:

I added the onClick line into my list.xml and wrote a method to show me a message when i click on the listview items. The thing is i can see the toast notification on my screen but listview clicklistener has never been executed in the method. Sorry, I am newbie in Android i think i might be doing something wrong in the list.xml.

click method:

```
public void myMethod(View view){

        Toast.makeText(this, "Try this.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        listemiz.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                myUrun=urunList.get(i);
                startActivity(new Intent(StokSayfasi.this,DetayliListe.class));
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: set Click listener in getVIew method at view

Comment: Just try to delete this line : myUrun=urunList.get(i); then try your application.

Comment: Just remove the android:clickable="false" from list.xml's RelativeLayout tag. You need to remove ScrollView also from there, just read about NestedScrollView.

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15352486/cant-click-on-items-in-listview-with-custom-adapter

Comment: @farhana i've already tried it , it didn't work :(

Comment: @ElMaravilla i tried, but it still the same :(

Comment: @ShailendraYadav i removed the clickable from the RelativeLayout but nothing changed. I've never tried the NestedScrollView in my apps, i will read that, thanks

Comment: You have used in activity setOnItemClickListener, remove this and add listener in Adapter

Comment: @Ankita i've tried the descendantFocusability solution and clickListener in getView method but they both didn't work for me

Comment: You have used android:clickable="false" in ScrollView also, you need to remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Can also use listview setOnItemnClickListener method for item click

Check Following Code :

```
listView1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                    long id) {

                String item = ((TextView)view).getText().toString();

                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });
```

Use this code in your xml and check. Hope this will work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"></ListView>

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />


        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: I can't see any toast info on my screen :(

Comment: Have you removed Clickable false from relative layout and scrollview ?

Comment: yeah, but in linearlayout there is still clickable=false line. should i remove it too?

Comment: and works fine with that xml! I used clickListener inside getView() and used your xml they together works perfectly fine. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

You can directly add on clickListener inside getView()

```
 @Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
    View satirView=null;

    if(satirView==null) {


        satirView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.anasayfalist, null);
    }
    TextView textView =
            (TextView) satirView.findViewById(R.id.stokName);
    TextView textViewcount =
            (TextView) satirView.findViewById(R.id.stokCount);

    Urun asset = urunListesi.get(position);

    textView.setText(asset.getName());
    textViewcount.setText("Toplam Stok: "+asset.getQuantity());


satirView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });

    return satirView;
}
```

and change the height of list.xml to wrap_content

Comment: I add a Log.d line into the onClick method to see if it is working but i can't see any messages on my screen

Comment: can you debug that?because it is working fine in my application

Comment: it seems that it doesn't go into onClick method. getView method works fine but the clickListener is not executing in the debugging

Comment: no, i just click on my listview items and nothing happens :(

Answer (score 0):

You can set onclick listener for LinearLayout in adapter's getView method. or debug the code at onitemClickListener to find the issue

Comment: this looks a mere guess...and not the answer.